# Need a match of a string which has two of the same characters

Tags: regex

Complete newbie to Regex, I need a regular expression which matches strings which start and end in the same character, and in between can be anything (even numbers)

I've tried some things, but I can't get it to match the text cases which are:

```
5 (true)
a (true)
b (true)
ab  (false)
aba (true)
```

`"(\"|\')whatever\\1"` is what I have so far, but it isnt working for all strings

Comment: How about `^(\w)\w*\1$|^(\w)$` using the second pattern to catch the single character cases? https://regex101.com/r/4WXnIO/4/

Comment: that gives me false when i try to match it on anything?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that (possibly the code you're using to match), it's matching the patterns just fine in the Regex101 tester.

Comment: Slightly updated pattern https://regex101.com/r/4WXnIO/5 `^(\w).*\1$|^(\w)$`

Comment: @Mako212 Why are you only matching `\w`? Also, that won't work for a 1-character string.

Comment: @Barmar I went with `\w` to limit how generalized the statement. It's not clear if OP wants to match say, `^asdfklj^` or not. So yes, we could make a very generalized version `^(.).*\1$|^(.)$`, but it's not clear that's a better answer to OPs question. And the second part of the statement after `|` handles the single character case.

Comment: Since his own attempt specifically matches just quotes, I think it's safe to say that he wants something more general than just alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @Mako212 I used your updated pattern, and that worked :) Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
^.$|^(.).*\1$
```

The case of a 1-character string is treated specially, since you can't match the same character twice in a pattern. The second alternative puts the first character in a capture group, then matches it at the end with a back-reference.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Al6zgw/1)

Another way to handle the 1-character case is by making everything after the first character optional.

```
^(.)(?:.*\1)?$
```

Comment: `^(.)(.*\1)?$` ?

Comment: Why would a capture group be needed around the rest of it?

Comment: Ah, you're showing how to do it without the alternatives.

Comment: @jhnc I added that version, using a non-capture group.